# Can we create bandwidth Limit for all users

Tags: server, 14.04, bandwidth

Can we create bandwidth limits for all users?

I want to share internet through my Ubuntu Server. Is this possible or not?

Comment: I did investigate this over a year ago. I will need to research my notes.

Answer (score -1):

Sharing Internet Connection is easy, and DpN has already provided a possible solution to that through a GUI. Alternatively, you can use `iptables` and `masquerading` to achieve the same, though it'll be without a GUI. More information can be had on http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/firewall-examples.html

Following is a sample script that you can run on the server. You can provide the gateway of this server to other machines so that they can access internet through this.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\n\nSETTING UP IPTABLES PROXY..."

INTIF="eth0"
EXTIF="eth1"
EXTIP="your.static.IP.address"

echo "Loading required stateful/NAT kernel modules..."

/sbin/depmod -a
/sbin/modprobe ip_tables
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_irc
/sbin/modprobe iptable_nat
/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_ftp
/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_irc

echo "    Enabling IP forwarding..."
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

echo "    Loading proxy server rules..."

# Clearing any existing rules and setting default policy
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT 
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD 
iptables -t nat -F

# FWD: Allow all connections OUT and only existing and related ones IN
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT

# Enabling SNAT (MASQUERADE) functionality on $EXTIF
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE

echo -e "       Proxy server rule loading complete\n\n"
```

However, managing / limiting bandwidth (also called traffic shaping) is a different ball game. You would need to have some advanced knowledge of the tools to be used and what your needs would be. There are some external firwalls such as [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) which help you manage it pretty well, but it'll require a different type of network setup.

Comment: "However, managing / limiting bandwidth (also called traffic shaping) is a different ball game." -- well, that is exactly what he asked for, so I'm not sure what the purpose is of the rest of your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the title. The second part of the question was about sharing internet connectivity through the server.